# How to calculate highest CCU (concurrent users) in server linux?

Tags: linux, jmeter

I used Jmeter to test stress of my application, i can check information of server RAM, CPU while testing.
Base on the information, how can i calculate value of highest CCU (concurrent users) while the server can run well.

Answer (score 0):

[Formula](http://support.loadimpact.com/knowledgebase/articles/265461-calculating-the-number-of-concurrent-users-to-test): Hourly Sessions x Average Session Duration (in seconds) / 3,600